# What happens if a Windows authenticated user has been downgraded from Admin to guest

Tags: sql-server

I have a Admin user in SQL user who is a Windows user(Windows authentication).
I have removed that user from admin group on windows and added as a Normal/Guest user.

What happens to my SQL server level privilege if I login with Windows authentication? Will it be same as earlier or it will changed as the Windows account has been downgraded and windows privileges has been reduced?

Answer (score 1):

The permissions of a user AD account in the domain and the permissions the user/login itself has within SQL server are completely separate. An AD user could have the lowest permissions possible on the domain but still be a `sysadmin` on SQL Server, and vice versa.

You can, however, use AD roles to provide permissions on SQL Server. If the AD user has been removed from roles in the AD, which also have permissions on SQL Server, they would have those permissions revoked. Conversely if they are added to an AD group that has permissions on SQL Server, then would gain those `GRANT`/`DENY` permissions. What those permissions are is completely specific to your environment.